# Problema al serializar un ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, poo, xml, arraylist, serialización

Llevo un tiempo tratando de serializar un ArrayList en Java, pero no termino de dar con ello.

La estructura jerárquica de mi programa es la siguiente: tengo una clase `Propiedad` de la cual heredan `Vivienda`, `Local`, `Vehiculo electrico`, `Vehiculo combustion` y alguna otra.
El programa lleva un registro de las propiedades que tienen los vecinos de un vecindario. Por lo que dentro de la clase vecino tenemos la lista de propiedades, diferente para cada nuevo vecino `ArrayList<Propiedad> listaPropiedades= new ArrayList<>();` , que al ser de tipo `Propiedad`puede contener objetos de tipo `Vivienda`, `Local`, etcetera por temas de herencia.

Él metodo al que he llegado para serializar, ubicado dentro de la clase vecino, es este:

```java
public static void XMLSerialization(ArrayList<Propiedad> lista, String nomFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nomFile);
        XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(fos);
        encoder.writeObject(lista);
        encoder.close();
        fos.close();
    }
```

Y desde la clase principal lo llamaríamos de la siguiente forma:

```java
Vecino.XMLSerialization(vec1.listaPropiedades,"Vecino1.xml");
Vecino.XMLSerialization(vec2.listaPropiedades,"Vecino2.xml");
```

El problema es que funciona, pero no del todo, pues solo serializa las viviendas. El arraylist de propiedades de cada vecino tiene muchas mas cosas a parte de viviendas, pero por algun motivo en el archivo XML solo aparecen serializadas las viviendas. No tengo ni idea de que ocurre.

EL archivo XML para el primer vecino por ejemplo, es este:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="20.0.1" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="com.mycompany.practicapoo.Vivienda">
    <void property="emisionesCo2">
     <double>13.6</double>
    </void>
    <void property="metrosTotales">
     <double>500.0</double>
    </void>
    <void property="zonaVivienda">
     <string>centro</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
  <void method="add">
   <object class="com.mycompany.practicapoo.Vivienda">
    <void property="emisionesCo2">
     <double>35.0</double>
    </void>
    <void property="metrosTotales">
     <double>6000.0</double>
    </void>
    <void property="zonaVivienda">
     <string>alfoz</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

¿Cómo hago para que se serialicen el resto de propiedades de los vecinos? La idea sería generar un fichero XML para cada vecino donde aparezcan registradas todas y cada una de sus propiedades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la serialización ocurra es necesario que todas las clases que se quieran serializar implementen la interfaz Serializable, tengan un constructor vacío, y que los atributos que quieran serializarse estén debidamente encapsuladas con getters y setters. En este caso el problema no está en el método XMLSerialization, si no en las clases en sí, que no eran serializables.

Comment: Esto qué es? Una respuesta?? Podrías explicar el por qué de esa necesidad. Una ampliación de tu pregunta? Deberías ponerla en la propia pregunta usando el enlace "Editar" que tienes bajo la misma. Si es una respuesta, por favor utiliza el enlace [edit] y explica un poco porque tal cual está, a mi me parece más un requerimiento de tu pregunta que una respuesta a la misma.

Comment: Es la respuesta a mi pregunta.

Comment: Buenisimo!! podrias ampliar tu respuesta con ejemplos de codigo entonces

Comment: Ahora si parece una respuesta! Recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema sepa que esta es la solución correcta!